# Changing the sender of a Dynamics CRM e-mail in a plugin?

Tags: dynamics-crm

So, here's my situation.  We have a department that needs the ability to use queues in CRM 4. They also need the ability to reply to e-mails that come to that queue from their department e-mail address.  (So that any customer responses will go back to the queue to be handled by agents)

I originally was going to build a JavaScript customization that inserted a checkbox that said "Send From Business Unit".  Toggling this would look up their department user based on the e-mail address on the Business Unit.  I successfully got this working (as a concept), but found that actually sending triggers the dreaded "CrmCheckPrivilege failed."

Which is good, because that means CRM is actually enforcing security.

So my problem? I have no idea how to replicate this functionality and it's a must have for this customer group.  Is there anyway to modify the e-mail after it's already gone through security checks via a plugin? Perhaps a pre-stage send plugin?

I want to be reasonably certain of success before I commit a lot of time to this solution. I'm also open to any other ideas too.

Thanks in advance,

Clif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, a "CrmPrivilegeCheck failed" can always be fixed by adjusting the user's roles and giving him the appropriate privilege (the privilegeId is always returned in the exception but may not be shown in the particular error dialog you are getting) and level, but this may not be wanted by the department.

A solution we have used is just slightly different from yours: Do not send the mails through another user, but through the queue. Queues can also be eMail senders in MSCRM. The queues should already have the correct eMail addresses set in order to work properly with the eMail router. Set up a way to determine the correct queue (like a field on the `systemuser` entity or a hardcoded queue name in your JavaScript) and set the `from` lookup accordingly in your JavaScript. That way the eMails will be sent using the name and address of the queue, so any direct replies will always have that queue as the recipient.

Comment: Thank you for your response...so glad someone else has worked on a problem like this :)  The reason we aren't granting that privilige is that it seems it is an all or nothing privilige.  Either all users with the permission are able to send as ANY other CRM user or they are allowed to send as none. How did you get around this potential security concern?

Comment: We didn't, because it wasn't considered an issue in that case. Does that privilege also control sending mails through a queue ? I haven't tried that. Other than that - what I think should always work is modifying the sender in a plugin, as you originally indended, using impersonation.

Comment: Going ahead and giving you credit. Didn't realize queues are valid senders and that anyone can send from them when I asked this.  Stupid I know!  Anyway, after we figured this out we just wrote a plugin that determines the correct queue and prevented them from changing it to another queue by editing the form.